# How to draw lines in Famous?

Tags: javascript, geometry, line, famo.us, famous-angular

How would one go about drawing a line dynamically in Famou.us ?

I would have thought there would be in innate function or something ?  Must we transform a 2D surface into a 1D line ?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26886424/how-to-simply-draw-a-line-in-famo-us

Comment: thank yo very much !